# Single Board Computer with Windows Support and NVidia GPU

Tags: embedded-systems

A widely used single board computer is the Nvidia Jetson, however, Windows is not supported. Due to driver support we are limited to Windows machines, but also require an Nvidia GPU with CUDA support.

Which single board computers support Windows and contain an Nvidia GPU?

Comment: Try looking for industrial SFF computers? Or take the motherboard out of a laptop? You might find something like a mini ITX motherboard that has a built-in GPU instead of a PCIe slot.

Comment: With Romen on this. Also, how much GPU power do you need/what form factor do you require? An SBC may not cut it on horsepower

Comment: I have heared that AMDGPUs now also support cuda via rocm